# How do you do flexible, same height paragraphs without a min-height attribute?

Tags: css, responsive-design

So here is an issue:

Web sites features 4 columns with descriptions, each inside the `<p>` element.

The problem: since text size differs by column, some columns are shorter than the others and when using a mobile phone or a tablet, they appear like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQzxP.jpg

How would one solve such issue? At first I have tried the min-height attribute but since there are so many resolutions, and sometimes I split into 4 instead of 2 columns per row, depending on device, setting min height for each resolution is a pain.

Is there any other way to do that?

Site: https://www.piere.lt

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be using some javacript to equal the height of all columns; there are a lot of libraries like http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

A suggestion: use `pure-u-md-1-2 pure-u-lg-1-4` to show items 2 by 2 at lower resolutions

Comment: I believe there is a way just to use some sort of wrapper? No JS

Comment: maybe using an higher min-height (just to make sure that the higher column sets the correct height for the others).
I've seen some errors in your HTML (a <p> inside an <ul>?) and some CSS I don't understand (why floating the <p> inside the column?)